# Unable to debug java app through stack driver in google kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-debugger

I am trying to debug a java app on GKE cluster through stack driver. 
I have created a GKE cluster with `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs`
I am following documentation: https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/java

Here is my DockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} alnt-watchlist-microservice.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/alnt-watchlist-microservice.jar"]
```

In documentation, it was written to add following lines in DockeFile:

```
RUN  mkdir /opt/cdbg && \
     wget -qO- https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-debugger/compute-java/debian-wheezy/cdbg_java_agent_gce.tar.gz | \
     tar xvz -C /opt/cdbg

RUN java -agentpath:/opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent.so 
    -Dcom.google.cdbg.module=tpm-watchlist
    -Dcom.google.cdbg.version=v1
    -jar /alnt-watchlist-microservice.jar
```

When I build DockerFile, It fails saying tar: invalid magic , tar: short read.

In stackdriver debug console, It always show 'No deployed application found'. Which application it will show? I have already 2 services deployed on my kubernetes cluster.

I have already executed 
`gcloud debug source gen-repo-info-file --output-directory="WEB-INF/classes/`
in my project's directory.

It generated source-context.json. After its creation, I tried building docker image and its failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.

Firstly, you will have to use java image "gcr.io/google-appengine/openjdk" instead of Alpine one.

Secondly,
I was putting entry points without comma separated (Basically in wrong format)

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-agentpath:/opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent.so", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"  ,"-Dcom.google.cdbg.module=watchlist"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The debugger will be ready for use when you deploy your containerized app. You are getting `No deployed application found` error because your debugger agent is failing to download or unzip in dockerfile.

Please check [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302192/how-to-solve-tar-invalid-magic-error-on-linux-alpine) to resolve the `tar: invalid magic , tar: short read.` error.

Comment: There were 2 options: Either you manually download and extract opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent.so or enable give access to all cloud APIs. I chose later one. I dont think I need to extract agent now. 
I have also used Google-provided base images for Java. Anything else I need to do? I am still not able to see any application to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like Alpine isn't regularly tested with Debugger. There's a sample setup here that might help you: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java#alpine-linux